# React Color doesn't let to change the color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-color

I'm using [React Color](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#examples) for my project. So I added `ChromePicker` as in the example into the code.

When the button is clicked, the picker is shown, when it's clicked outside of it - it gets closed. So far so good, it works as expected.

But if I try to change the color, to move the circle or the bars below the gradient there is no action, they are not moving. I don't know why is this happening.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { ChromePicker } from 'react-color';

export default class Banner extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayColorPicker: false,
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ displayColorPicker: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ displayColorPicker: false });
  };

  render() {
    const popover = {
      position: 'absolute',
      zIndex: '2',
    };
    const cover = {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0px',
      right: '0px',
      bottom: '0px',
      left: '0px',
    };

    return ( 
       <div>
        ...//some other code
        <div>
          <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Pick Color</Button>
          {this.state.displayColorPicker ? (
            <div style={popover}>
              <div
                style={cover}
                onClick={this.handleClose}
                onKeyDown={this.handleClick}
                role="button"
                tabIndex="0"
                aria-label="Save"
              />
              <ChromePicker />
            </div>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';

class Component extends React.Component {
  state = {
    background: '#fff',
  };

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SketchPicker
        color={ this.state.background }
        onChangeComplete={ this.handleChangeComplete }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You should use the ***onChangeComplete*** props I suppose, you can find further info [here](https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#usage-include)

Answer (score 1):

This issue might answer your question: https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/issues/717

Something was changed between version 2.17 and 2.18, you need to either downgrade or make controlled component.